Why List<T> uses its own cached empty array instead of Array.Empty<T>?
The List<T> code in question is:
#pragma warning disable CA1825, IDE0300 // avoid the extra generic instantiation for Array.Empty<T>()
        private static readonly T[] s_emptyArray = new T[0];
#pragma warning restore CA1825, IDE0300

This cached empty array is used, for instance, when List<T>.ToArray() is called and the list is empty.
Now, why does this custom caching of an empty array exist, and why is Array.Empty<T>() seen as an "extra generic instantiation" that needs to be avoided? Wouldn't it be the case that, during runtime, if Array.Empty<T>() is used elsewhere, s_emptyArray would become the "extra" instantiation because there would now be two cached empty instances? Or is this about avoiding some performance impact arising from Array.Empty<T>(), which delegates to the static class EmptyArray<T> that contains the actual empty array? Is the performance impact of this generic access (I wouldn't quite call it "instantiation," as the code comment does) significant enough to justify having a custom cached empty array and potentially two instances of empty arrays during runtime? Should we also consider creating and using our own cached empty arrays in high-performance scenarios?

This avoids the need to create the generic type EmptyArray<T> for the type parameter T in question if not needed. I don't think it has any performance impact.

@KlausGütter Can you explain what is the purpose of avoiding to create the generic type?

Saves a few bytes of metadata in the assembly and one Type instance per T. Looks like a micro-optimization that is only justified in such an extremely often used type.

As far back as I can see in the git history https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.0.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs this dates back to at least 2015, even though Array.Empty was already available https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/40705020f56b7634f247e355b1745df362ecd9a7/src/mscorlib/src/System/Array.cs#L1056 it may be the case that when the code was inserted that it wasn't available and noone bothered to update. Array.Empty was also introduced in Framework 4.6 which came out in 2014, so that dates that.

This not only avoids the generic call to Array.Empty<T>(), but also creating a new generic type EmptyArray<T> for every List<T>. Since every new generic type introduced at runtime comes with a small overhead (JIT and memory usage) this can accumulate, because List'1 is extremely widely used for many different T's.

So there is an assumption that it's more likely that only the list needs the empty array and that there is no other Array.Empty<T>() call in the codebase for the same T. Because if there would be such a call we'd get the overhead of EmptyArray<T> anyway plus the overhead of the extra array instance inside the list.

This avoids the need to create the generic type EmptyArray<T> for the type parameter T in question if not needed.
I don't think it has any performance impact. But it saves a few bytes of metadata in the assembly and one Type instance per T. Looks like a micro-optimization that is only justified in such an extremely often used type like List<T>.
